# Compile error in Eclipse - Method refers to missing type

Tags: java, eclipse, message

I have written the following two lines:

```
OCLContextDefinitionMCParser parser = new OCLContextDefinitionMCParser();
Optional<ASTOCLContextDefinition> invariant = parser.parse(model.toString());
```

(whereas `model` is of type `Path` and it points to a filename)

But the method `parse` is underlined with a red line by eclipse. The corresponding error message is the following one:

```
The method parse(String) from type OCLContextDefinitionMCParser 
refers to the missing type ASTOCLContextDefinition
```

When I look into the signature of `parse` located in `OCLContextDefinitionMCParser`, then I can see:

```
public Optional<oclgrammarDefinition.oclgrammarDefinition._ast.ASTOCLContextDefinition> parse(String filename) throws IOException, RecognitionException {
...
}
```

So, I can not understand the error message. I also add the imports. But somehow, `parse` is still underlined.

Here, are a part of the content of *Problems* view:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
ASTAnyExpr cannot be resolved to a type ASTOCLAnyExpression.java    /oclgrammar/target/generated-sources/monticore/sourcecode/oclgrammar/oclgrammar/_ast    line 105    Java Problem
ASTAnyExpr cannot be resolved to a type ASTOCLAnyExpression.java    /oclgrammar/target/generated-sources/monticore/sourcecode/oclgrammar/oclgrammar/_ast    line 106    Java Problem
ASTAnyExpr cannot be resolved to a type ASTOCLAnyExpression.java    /oclgrammar/target/generated-sources/monticore/sourcecode/oclgrammar/oclgrammar/_ast    line 106    Java Problem
ASTAnyExpr cannot be resolved to a type ASTOCLAnyExpression.java    /oclgrammar/target/generated-sources/monticore/sourcecode/oclgrammar/oclgrammar/_ast    line 156    Java Problem
ASTAnyExpr cannot be resolved to a type ASTOCLAnyExpression.java    /oclgrammar/target/generated-sources/monticore/sourcecode/oclgrammar/oclgrammar/_ast    line 157    Java Problem
ASTAnyExpr cannot be resolved to a type ASTOCLAnyExpression.java    /oclgrammar/target/generated-sources/monticore/sourcecode/oclgrammar/oclgrammar/_ast    line 157    Java Problem
ASTAnyExpr cannot be resolved to a type ASTOCLAnyExpression.java    /oclgrammar/target/generated-sources/monticore/sourcecode/oclgrammar/oclgrammar/_ast    line 316    Java Problem
ASTAnyExpr cannot be resolved to a type ASTOCLAnyExpression.java    /oclgrammar/target/generated-sources/monticore/sourcecode/oclgrammar/oclgrammar/_ast    line 317    Java Problem
ASTAnyExpr cannot be resolved to a type ASTOCLAnyExpression.java    /oclgrammar/target/generated-sources/monticore/sourcecode/oclgrammar/oclgrammar/_ast    line 359    Java Problem
ASTAnyExpr cannot be resolved to a type ASTOCLAnyExpression.java    /oclgrammar/target/generated-sources/monticore/sourcecode/oclgrammar/oclgrammar/_ast    line 359    Java Problem
ASTAnyExpr cannot be resolved to a type ASTOCLAnyExpression.java    /oclgrammar/target/generated-sources/monticore/sourcecode/oclgrammar/oclgrammar/_ast    line 412    Java Problem
ASTAnyExpr cannot be resolved to a type ASTOCLAnyExpression.java    /oclgrammar/target/generated-sources/monticore/sourcecode/oclgrammar/oclgrammar/_ast    line 496    Java Problem
ASTAnyExpr cannot be resolved to a type ASTOCLAnyExpression.java    /oclgrammar/target/generated-sources/monticore/sourcecode/oclgrammar/oclgrammar/_ast    line 507    Java Problem
ASTAnyExpr cannot be resolved to a type AnyExprMCParser.java    /oclgrammar/target/generated-sources/monticore/sourcecode/oclgrammar/oclgrammar/_parser line 99 Java Problem
ASTAnyExpr cannot be resolved to a type AnyExprMCParser.java    /oclgrammar/target/generated-sources/monticore/sourcecode/oclgrammar/oclgrammar/_parser line 102    Java Problem
ASTAnyExpr cannot be resolved to a type OCLGrammarASTAnyExprCoCo.java   /oclgrammar/target/generated-sources/monticore/sourcecode/oclgrammar/oclgrammar/_cocos  line 9  Java Problem
ASTAnyExpr cannot be resolved to a type OCLGrammarCoCoChecker.java  /oclgrammar/target/generated-sources/monticore/sourcecode/oclgrammar/oclgrammar/_cocos  line 408    Java Problem
ASTAnyExpr cannot be resolved to a type OCLGrammarInheritanceVisitor.java   /oclgrammar/target/generated-sources/monticore/sourcecode/oclgrammar/oclgrammar/_visitor    line 212    Java Problem
ASTAnyExprList cannot be resolved to a type OCLGrammarASTAnyExprListCoCo.java   /oclgrammar/target/generated-sources/monticore/sourcecode/oclgrammar/oclgrammar/_cocos  line 9  Java Problem
ASTIfThenElseStatement cannot be resolved to a type ASTOCLIfThenElseExpr.java   /oclgrammar/target/generated-sources/monticore/sourcecode/oclgrammar/oclgrammar/_ast    line 105    Java Problem
ASTIfThenElseStatement cannot be resolved to a type ASTOCLIfThenElseExpr.java   /oclgrammar/target/generated-sources/monticore/sourcecode/oclgrammar/oclgrammar/_ast    line 106    Java Problem
ASTIfThenElseStatement cannot be resolved to a type ASTOCLIfThenElseExpr.java   /oclgrammar/target/generated-sources/monticore/sourcecode/oclgrammar/oclgrammar/_ast    line 106    Java Problem
ASTIfThenElseStatement cannot be resolved to a type ASTOCLIfThenElseExpr.java   /oclgrammar/target/generated-sources/monticore/sourcecode/oclgrammar/oclgrammar/_ast    line 156    Java Problem
ASTIfThenElseStatement cannot be resolved to a type ASTOCLIfThenElseExpr.java   /oclgrammar/target/generated-sources/monticore/sourcecode/oclgrammar/oclgrammar/_ast    line 157    Java Problem
ASTIfThenElseStatement cannot be resolved to a type ASTOCLIfThenElseExpr.java   /oclgrammar/target/generated-sources/monticore/sourcecode/oclgrammar/oclgrammar/_ast    line 157    Java Problem
ASTIfThenElseStatement cannot be resolved to a type ASTOCLIfThenElseExpr.java   /oclgrammar/target/generated-sources/monticore/sourcecode/oclgrammar/oclgrammar/_ast    line 314    Java Problem
ASTIfThenElseStatement cannot be resolved to a type ASTOCLIfThenElseExpr.java   /oclgrammar/target/generated-sources/monticore/sourcecode/oclgrammar/oclgrammar/_ast    line 315    Java Problem
ASTIfThenElseStatement cannot be resolved to a type ASTOCLIfThenElseExpr.java   /oclgrammar/target/generated-sources/monticore/sourcecode/oclgrammar/oclgrammar/_ast    line 359    Java Problem
ASTIfThenElseStatement cannot be resolved to a type ASTOCLIfThenElseExpr.java   /oclgrammar/target/generated-sources/monticore/sourcecode/oclgrammar/oclgrammar/_ast    line 359    Java Problem
ASTIfThenElseStatement cannot be resolved to a type ASTOCLIfThenElseExpr.java   /oclgrammar/target/generated-sources/monticore/sourcecode/oclgrammar/oclgrammar/_ast    line 412    Java Problem
ASTIfThenElseStatement cannot be resolved to a type ASTOCLIfThenElseExpr.java   /oclgrammar/target/generated-sources/monticore/sourcecode/oclgrammar/oclgrammar/_ast    line 487    Java Problem
ASTIfThenElseStatement cannot be resolved to a type ASTOCLIfThenElseExpr.java   /oclgrammar/target/generated-sources/monticore/sourcecode/oclgrammar/oclgrammar/_ast    line 498    Java Problem
ASTIfThenElseStatement cannot be resolved to a type ASTOCLIfThenElseExpr.java   /oclgrammar/target/generated-sources/monticore/sourcecode/oclgrammar/oclgrammar/_ast    line 573    Java Problem
ASTIfThenElseStatement cannot be resolved to a type ASTOCLIfThenElseExpr.java   /oclgrammar/target/generated-sources/monticore/sourcecode/oclgrammar/oclgrammar/_ast    line 592    Java Problem
ASTIfThenElseStatement cannot be resolved to a type IfThenElseStatementMCParser.java    /oclgrammar/target/generated-sources/monticore/sourcecode/oclgrammar/oclgrammar/_parser line 99 Java Problem
ASTIfThenElseStatement cannot be resolved to a type IfThenElseStatementMCParser.java    /oclgrammar/target/generated-sources/monticore/sourcecode/oclgrammar/oclgrammar/_parser line 102    Java Problem
ASTIfThenElseStatement cannot be resolved to a type OCLGrammarASTIfThenElseStatementCoCo.java   /oclgrammar/target/generated-sources/monticore/sourcecode/oclgrammar/oclgrammar/_cocos  line 9  Java Problem
```

Comment: It seems that there is no jar in your project build path that contains the class oclgrammarDefinition.oclgrammarDefinition._ast.ASTOCLContextDefinition. You're missing a library.

Comment: I use eclipse for the first time. I do not know what that means

Comment: Right click on your project, choose "configure build path", and add the missing library (i.e. jar file).

Comment: All libraries are there. When I click on the "Libraries" tab, then I can see there all libs which I use. I have no other library to add.

Comment: And yet, Eclipse complains about a missing class... When you type Ctrl-shift-T (or Cmd-shift-T on Mac), then type `ASTOCLContextDefinition` in the type name, does it find the class?

Comment: yes, when I do that, then eclipse finds the class.

Comment: @JBNizet:But the 'parse' method is still underlined.

Comment: Do you have any compilation error in the "Markers" view? Can you post a complete example reproducing the problem?

Comment: Where I can find the "Markers" View. I have only a "Problems", "Javadoc" "Declaration" and a "Console" view at the bottom.

Comment: Window - Show View. But the Problems view shows the same information.

Comment: I have added the "Problems" view. You can see it above. I had to limit the content because only 30000 characters are allowed. I know there is only ASTAnyExpr and ASTIfthenElseStatement, but I have also the same messages about ASTOCLContextDefinition

Comment: `cannot be resolved to a type` means that imports are missing in the generated source code.

Comment: What I have tried before the errors appear was the following: I need to write test cases for the generated source code with JUnit. Therefore, I right-click on the package (where the generated code resides) -> Build path -> Use as source folder.This is the only way I know. But then the imports are not correct anymore. Is there another elegant way how to do that in eclipse? I posted another question about that, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30955168/eclipse-can-not-find-junit-test-case-folder-how-to-configure-it?noredirect=1#comment49943894_30955168   But without success.

Comment: The source folder must NOT be the folder corresponding to the package. It must be the folder containing the root package. So, if you have a class `com.foo.SomeClass`, the source folder must be the folder containing (i.e. *above*) `com`.

Comment: Ok, I have tried it. But now, I get the following error message: "Error while adding to build path  Reason: Cannot nest output folder 'ocl/target/classes' inside 'ocl/target' " .